# unable to use --noproxy option with curl 0.8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I have a Ruby on Rails web application in which I am attempting to use the --noproxy option while launching a curl command like so...

curl --noproxy -e "https://site.to.scrape"

I can do this on my local server no problem.  However, when I push the code to the production server, I get the following error:

curl: option --noproxy: is unknown

The curb gem is exactly the same - 0.8.1 - for both servers.  I just don't know why I can't use the --noproxy option for the production server.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

I assume curl is reading the proxy address from the environment variable `http_proxy` and that the variable should keep its value. Then in a shell like bash, `export http_proxy='';` before a command (or in a shell script) would temporarily change its value,  or simply `unset http_proxy`.

(See curl's manual for all the variables it looks at, under the `ENVIRONMENT` heading.)